# If $\{f_n\}$ is $L^1$-weakly convergent sequence then $\{f_n\}$ converges in measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a $L^1$-weakly convergent sequence to $f\in L^1$.

Can we say that $\{f_n\}$  converges in measure to $f$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fact:** if $(f_n) \subset L^1$ converges weakly to $f \in L^1$, then $f_n \to f$ in measure if and only if $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. This holds if we only assume that $(f_n)$ is weakly relatively compact.

Indeed, if $(f_n)$ converges weakly in $L^1$ then it is weakly relatively compact. By the Dunford-Pettis theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability)), it is uniformly integrable. For a uniformly integrable sequence, it is well known that convergence in measure and $L^1$-convergence are equivalent.

To answer your question, take any sequence converging weakly in $L^1$ but not strongly. It will not converge in measure.

Comment: If $\{f_n\}$ is weakly convergence then $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence converges in measure?

Comment: You run into a similar issue: if $(f_n)$ converges weakly then any subsequence converging in measure will also converge in $L^1$ by the above statement. So it is enough to find a sequence $(f_n)$ converging weakly in $L^1$ but admitting no subsequence converging strongly. Take $f_n(x) = e^{inx}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma it converges weakly to $0$ in $L^1([-\pi,\pi])$. But $\lVert f_n \rVert_{L^1} = 2\pi$ so no subsequence can converge strongly.

Comment: What can we say: if $\{f_n\}$ is bounded in $L^1$?

Comment: Not much more since the assumption $(f_n)$ converges weakly is *stronger* than $(f_n)$ bounded in $L^1$.

Comment: Sir, a bounded sequence in $ L ^ 1 $ does not have a converging subsequence in $ L^1 $?

Comment: No, just consider the same counterexample as before $f_n(x) = e^{inx}$.